# Scrolling on a infinite loop animation react

Tags: tailwind-ui

I have a array of Reviews that "autoscrolling" along the pages.

I would like to also be able to scroll them.

I have tried <overflow-x-scroll> and put on a ticker that scrolls every second, but it ended up lagging a lot, so now I animation as seen below.  You can also se the relevant react code. I am using tailwind.

```
future: {
        hoverOnlyWhenSupported: true,
      },



 <div className="relative m-auto w-[100%] overflow-hidden">
        <div className="animate-infinite-slider hover:pause flex>
          {reviews?.data?.map((review: any, i: any) => {
            const userPhotoUrl = "" + review.image;
```

I have tried <overflow-x-scroll> and put on a ticker that scrolls every second, but it ended up lagging a lot, so now I animation as seen below.  You can also se the relevant react code. I am using tailwind.

```
future: {
        hoverOnlyWhenSupported: true,
      },



 <div className="relative m-auto w-[100%] overflow-hidden">
        <div className="animate-infinite-slider hover:pause flex>
          {reviews?.data?.map((review: any, i: any) => {
            const userPhotoUrl = "" + review.image;
```